# Remove perl package completely

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I am trying to uninstall the old perl package and install a new package. I used rpm -e to uninstall the old package. I could still see the below files after uninstalling. How can i completely remove the perl package from my server. It runs on OEL 6.10. And when I do "perl -v" , I could see 5.30 version as output, even after uninstalling perl.

```
/opt/CWx/perl
/opt/CWx/modules/installed/Module-Build-0.4005/inc/Perl
/opt/CWx/modules/installed/Perl-OSType-1.003/blib/lib/Perl
/opt/CWx/modules/installed/Perl-OSType-1.003/blib/lib/auto/Perl
/opt/CWx/modules/installed/Perl-OSType-1.003/blib/arch/auto/Perl
/opt/CWx/modules/installed/Perl-OSType-1.003/lib/Perl
/opt/CWx/modules/Module-Build-0.4208/inc/Perl
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-754.11.1.el6.x86_64/tools/perf/scripts/perl
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64/tools/perf/scripts/perl
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.x86_64/tools/perf/scripts/perl
/usr/local/share/perl5_old/Perl
/usr/local/bin/perl
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which package installed a file you can use the command:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides [filename]
```

For example, for the first file in your list:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides /opt/CWx/perl
```

None of the files you list are in locations which are used by the standard Perl RPM on a RedHat-based system. You will, I expect, find that they are either installed by a completely different package or not installed by a package at all.

And that will also explain why you can still access Perl. Those files include other versions of the Perl compiler and I bet that whoever installed them also changed the `PATH` so that you have access to at least one of them.

If you want to know which Perl installation is responding to your commands, just run this:

```
which perl
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I ran  rpm -q --whatprovides /opt/CWx/perl , I got output saying "file /opt/CWx/perl is not owned by any package" . So unable to figure out.

Comment: @VigneshSenthil: Right. That's what I thought. Those extra files aren't part of a package. They've been installed manually at some point. Unless you can talk to someone who knows the history of that installation, then there's nothing much you can do.

Comment: Sure . Thanks for the suggestion.